# Ruby On Rails: Duplicate Index User listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have Devise installed and have set up a UsersController. My UsersController looks like the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @users = User.all
    end

end
```

My routes currently look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'users#home'

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users, controller: :users
    scope "/admin" do
    resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :new]

end
```

I created an index page under my users folder with the following code:

```
<div class = 'container' style = 'width:750px'>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>User ID </th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= @users.each do |user| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= user.id %></td>
                    <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
                    <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
                    <td><%= user.email %></td>
                    <td><%= user.country_code %><%= user.phone_number %></td>
                </tr>
            <%end%>
        </tbody>
    </table>



</div>
```

Everything displays perfectly, but I keep receiving this above my table:

[image: Screenshot of index page]

This is a screenshot of what I am viewing with the text I want removed highlighted.

Please show me how I can fix this. Big thanks to all that submit!

Comment: Can you upload the image to a more *public* source?

Comment: http://imgur.com/O9FSneB  Let me know if this works.

Comment: Woops! I was late. See Zoran's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Zoran's answer did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your `@users.each` line to not use the `<%=`, like so:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In ERB, `<%= %>` evaluates and prints the result of the code contained within, whereas `<% %>` only evaluates the expression within.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome that worked! I can't believe I missed that :) Thank you!